# Use the same buffer for separate DATE and TIME

Tags: mysql, c, mysql-connector

I am using the MySQL C api along with prepared statements. When issuing a INSERT query with a TIME field the result is in HHH:MM:SS format, where the hours are the amount of hours elapsed this month. For instance if the date is 2015-02-21, and the time is 21:30:00 the time would be displayed as 525:30:00 but I want to use the HH:MM:SS format instead (e.g 21:30:00), which would be the actual time of the day.

```
sbind[3].buffer_type=MYSQL_TYPE_DATE;
sbind[3].buffer= (char *)&ts; // Pointer to a MYSQL_TIME data structure
sbind[3].is_null= 0;
sbind[3].length= 0;

sbind[4] = sbind[3];
sbind[4].buffer_type=MYSQL_TYPE_TIME;

mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, sbind); // sbind is an array of MYSQL_BIND structures

ts.year= 1900+tm_info->tm_year; // tm_info is a pointer to a tm structure
ts.month= 1+tm_info->tm_mon;
ts.day= tm_info->tm_mday;

ts.hour= tm_info->tm_hour;
ts.minute= tm_info->tm_min;
ts.second= tm_info->tm_sec;
```

This code will prepare the date field as yyyy-mm-dd and fill it with the date in tm_info. Likewise it will do the same thing for the time field but in the HHH:MM:SS format.

A unfashionable way which works is to use a separate MYSQL_TIME structure for the time, but I aim for a more elegant way to handle this.

(**EDIT:** Here I have included the relevant client side code

```
MYSQL_TIME  ts;
MYSQL_STMT *stmt;
MYSQL_BIND sbind[2];

...

char query[QUERY_BUFFER_SIZE];
strcpy(query, "INSERT INTO `mytable` (date,time) VALUES(?,?)");
if(mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, query, strlen(query))){
    return mysql_stmt_errno(stmt);
}

...

time_t rawtime;
time(&rawtime); // get current time
struct tm *tm_info = localtime ( &rawtime );

...

memset(sbind,0,sizeof(sbind));

sbind[0].buffer_type=MYSQL_TYPE_DATE;
sbind[0].buffer= (char *)&ts; // Pointer to a MYSQL_TIME data structure
sbind[0].is_null= 0;
sbind[0].length= 0;

sbind[1] = sbind[0];
sbind[1].buffer_type=MYSQL_TYPE_TIME;

mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, sbind); // sbind is an array of MYSQL_BIND structures

ts.year= 1900+tm_info->tm_year; // tm_info is a pointer to a tm structure
ts.month= 1+tm_info->tm_mon;
ts.day= tm_info->tm_mday;

ts.hour= tm_info->tm_hour;
ts.minute= tm_info->tm_min;
ts.second= tm_info->tm_sec;

if(mysql_stmt_execute(stmt)){
    return mysql_stmt_errno(stmt);
}
```

This assumes `mysql` is a valid connection. The table `mytable` in this case only contains a `DATE` type and a `TIME` type.

)

Comment: As I posted, there's nothing wrong with this. If you need something else, you need to better specify what you have and what you need.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I need to retrieve the current time of the day, but if I use the same MYSQL_TIME data structure for the time field and the date field it will be displayed in HHH:MM:SS as you mentioned, but I want it to be displayed as HH:MM:SS holding only the current time of the day (e.g 13:37:00)

Comment: Wait a second... you mark a buffer as `MYSQL_TYPE_TIME` but expect it to be handled like `DATETIME`? Please show all the relevant code... As it currently is, neither your binding nor your prepared value are ever used in any way. So I cannot figure out where the incorrect number of hours surfaces.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev No, I use two unique fields for both `MYSQL_TYPE_TIME` and `MYSQL_TYPE_DATE`. I just want to somehow tell MySQL to treat the time and the date individually without using a seperate `MYSQL_TIME` struct for DATE and TIME.

Comment: It is rare to split DATE and TIME into two separate fields in a MySQL table.  You are generally much better off having a single DATETIME field.  Then if you want just the date part or just the hour or (etc), perform some extraction operation on the DATETIME to get the part(s) you want.

Comment: @[c45602464](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651374/mysql-time-type-displays-time-in-hhhmmss#comment45602464_28651374) Well, I seem to already have figured it out, see the edit, but it never hurts anyway.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Alright, thanks for the tip and all the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the natural representation for the [`TIME` type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html) - it, as the name suggests, only holds time, and this is the natural way to express *time* larger than a day. It does, as the documentation suggests, use `HH:MM:SS` for smaller values.

Since `TIME` [does not care about shenanigans like leap seconds](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time-zone-leap-seconds.html), to exclude full days, just take `tm_hour%24`. But, to allow for shenanigans like DST transitions, you have nothing to do but add the `TIME` to the starting point of the specific month and do `DATETIME` arithmetic with the stock functions.

@[c45602234](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651374/mysql-time-type-displays-time-in-hhhmmss#comment45602234_28651374):

Trying to outsmart `libmysql` FAILED (`mysql-connector-c-6.1.5/libmysql/libmysql.c:1964`):

```
static void store_param_date(NET *net, MYSQL_BIND *param)
{
  MYSQL_TIME tm= *((MYSQL_TIME *) param->buffer);
  tm.hour= tm.minute= tm.second= tm.second_part= 0;
  net_store_datetime(net, &tm);
}
```

As you can see, it always uses up the entire structure (apparently, so that relevant functions always work as expected).